# Как сделать textbox прозрачным в WinForm C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать textbox прозрачным в WinForm C#?

Comment: Что именно должно сквозь него просвечивать: нижележащий контрол (форма) или десктоп/другое приложение?

Comment: прозрачность задаётся для формы, а не для конкретного элемента.

Comment: гугления [силу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) познать должен ты :)

Comment: Alexander Petrov, нижележащий контрол.

Comment: @Vladimir - ставьте значок `@` перед ником того, к кому обращаетесь. Без этого я не получил уведомление о вашем комментарии.

Comment: @Vladimir когда речь о каких-нибудь рюшечках, лучше все таки смотреть в сторону WPF или AlvaloniaUI. WinForms весьма не гибки в том плане, если Вам где-то необходимо отойти от заданного стандарта ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.BackColor = BackColor;                         
textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Работает 100%

Comment: А если на родительском контроле этого объекта изображение?

Comment: Вот да, что делать если изображение на нижележащем контроле

Comment: удалить изображение